# Execute python file with windows shortcut

Tags: python

I have a python code which takes as input an Excel file and the output is a picture (for example a graph). 
This works really well and I'm happy with that.

A friend of mine, who is unfamiliar with coding, would like to use this tool as well. Therefore I would like to make it easy for him and create a shortcut (Windows command) which can execute the script.

Is this possible, and if yes, how??

Comment: How do you execute this script without a shortcut? Is it a console app or does it have a GUI?

Comment: Thank you for the question: I have work in a python notebook. I still have to figure out how to code more efficient in that regard!

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of resources on the subject, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a shortcut to `c:/...Python.exe path/to/your/script.py`

Answer (score -1):

To build on Random Guy's answer, `pyinstaller` is most likely what you want. It will package up all your dependencies into a single executable.

I usually use this command when creating an exe.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed script.py --name Script
```

Answer (score -2):

You could create an exe with a tool such as Pyinstaller